# How to create such form: each db record has selection, with django forms?

Tags: django, forms, model

I have 2 things:

- list of fruits (eg.: apples, lemons, strawberries)
- list of answers (eg.: 'selling', 'making', 'both')

How can i merge these lists into django form which products something like the html [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2DVvG/).

The desired form would allow user to pick a ONE answer ('selling', 'making', 'both') for each fruit (apples, lemons, starberries)

I started with this:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    doing = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=fruits,
        widget=forms.Select(choices=choices),
    )
```

Comment: What are your views and template like?

Comment: what is `fruits` here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a quick solution like this:

```
FRUITS = [
    'apples', 'lemons', 'strawberries',
]  # hardcoded like here or from db

ANSWERS = [
    (0, u''),
    (1, u'selling'),
    (2, u'making'),
    (3, u'both'),
]  # hardcoded like here or from db

class ProblematicForm(forms.Form):
    # regluar fields goes here, like:
    regular_field = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProblematicForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for name in FRUITS:
            # Here we add our problematic fields
            self.fields[name] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ANSWERS)
```

This won't give fieldset (like in linked example), but it wouldn't have.
That's it \o/